# What is the time complexity of this pseudo-code

Tags: algorithm

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    for j in range(1, n+1, 1):
        if j % i > 0:
            for k in range(1, j+1, 1):
                sum += 1
```

based on what i have done so far we have:

```
sum = 0                                   -> 1
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):                -> n+1
    for j in range(1, n+1, 1):            -> n(n+1)
        if j % i > 0:                     -> n(n)
            for k in range(1, j+1, 1):    -> (n)(n) j+1
                sum += 1                  -> (n)(n) j
```

the time complexity will be O(j n^2) but i have some trouble figuring out the value of j.

we also have:

(times line 5 was executed) - (times line 6 was executed) = sum n-floor(n/i), i=2 to n

Comment: when considering Big O notation, I believe you have to consider the worst-case, in which j goes up to n. Thus you basically have a triple for loop(you do have a triple for loop). Thus the time complexity can be assumed to be O(n^3)

Comment: @AkaCoder404 i think the time complexity is more than O(n^3). considering the sum formula for n > n/2 we will have n/2 * (n-1) which is roughly n^2